# Regex for removing before number R

Tags: r, regex

How do you do a regex gsub for removing all terms from a string before the first number?

Regex is the bane of my existance. I know I'm close:

```
houston$address1 <- gsub("\\{num}.*","",houston$address1)
```

Happy to award the points to first to help me out. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it is something like:

```
^.*?(?=[0-9])
```

Or simpler

```
^[^0-9]*
```